# Fetching Data from Web Page to Excel

Tags: excel, parsing, web, automation

I want to fetch data & save it to Excel. Web data is the following format:

> **Kawal store** Rate this
>
> **Wz5a Delhi - 110018** | View Map
>
> **Call: XXXXXXXXXX**
>
> Distance : Less than 5 KM
>
> Also See : Grocery Stores
>
> Edit this
>
> Photos

I want to save only the **bold** fields in following format:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
```

Single search page contains different data formats; for example sometimes PHOTOS is not there.

Sample URL: http://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Grocery-Stores-%3Cnear%3E-Ramesh-Nagar/ct-70444/page-10

Page number can be changed to get other data in the series while keeping other URL same

Answer (score 0):

While generating an Actual excel file might be a heavy task, generating is CSV (Comma Seperated Values) is a much easier task, and CSV files are associated with all of the excel similar applications on both Windws, Mac, and all Linux distributions.

If you must insist on using Excel, [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is a ready-made PHP utility for that.

Otherwise you can use the integrated fputcsv php function:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['export']) && $_GET['export'] == 'csv'){
            header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
            header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
            $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            $myData = array (
                          array('1234', '567', 'efed', 'ddd'),//row1
                          array('123', '456', '789'),        //row2
                          array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')             //row3 
                         );

            foreach($myData as $row){
                 fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }

            fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

It's as easy is that, the following lines will output a csv file with rows and column, identical to the structure of the myData array, so basically you can replace it's content with whatever you'd like, even a result set from a DB.

[On more information about the CSV standard](http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format)